# Reorder box plots by median

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the `reorder` function but it doesn't sort the last few box plots by median.

[image]

My code:

```
p <- ggplot(JRdata, aes(
  x = reorder(as.factor(female), occlusion19, FUN = median), y = occlusion19, fill = FamilySelectionMetagenomics,
  colour = FamilySelectionMetagenomics
)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "red")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "black")) +
  xlab("Female") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 40)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 40)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20)) +
  ylab("Portion of Stomata Occluded /10") +
  ggtitle("Occlusion19") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 40)) +
  theme(element_blank()) +

  # add in labels for selected individua;s
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = ifelse(Family == "Y", paste0(female), "")),
    angle = 90, size = 10, nudge_y = 1
  ) +
  labs(caption = "Fig. 8. Average   stomatal occlusion at age 19 for 45 families from Jordan River GCA plot. Families selected for illumina sequencing have been highlighted in red. Occlusion scores were calculated as the proportion of
occluded stomata, averaged over 5mm middle sections of 10 needles randomly selected from 2nd year foliage, year 19 was assessed in May 2020 (0= 0% occluded stomata, 10 = 100% occluded stomata.)") +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(size = 25)) +
  theme(plot.caption.position = "plot", plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0)) +

  # format the legend
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 20)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 40)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())

# export figure
ggsave(
  plot = p, width = 40, height = 20, dpi = 300, limitsize = FALSE,
  filename = "occlusion19familyboxplot.pdf"
)
```

Comment: Hi Emma, do you have a sample of the data? I think you may be better making the x variable a factor and order its levels in the way that you want.

Comment: @Emma it's better if you can include at least a sample of your data that causes the problem and also minimise the code, e.g. if you remove everything after `geom_boxplot() +` do you still get the problem. It's easier for someone to replicate the problem then and suggest a fix. I'm wondering if you have some `NA` values in your data. Could you try adding `, na.rm = TRUE` after `FUN = median`?